# Orientation after if statement

Tags: iphone, ios

I have this code which calls this method (one that you un comment out to use)

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations

NSLog(@"So the orientation is %d", OrientationInteger); 


//1 is button to the left, 0 to the right.

if (OrientationInteger == 1) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    NSLog(@"setting Orientation landscape left");

}


if (OrientationInteger == 0) {
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    NSLog(@"setting Orientation landscape right");


}


else {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    NSLog(@"no instructions regarding orientation.");


}

}
```

However, the orientation does not change, nor does the log messages after the first fire.

```
    NSLog(@"So the orientation is %d", OrientationInteger);
```

gives 'So the orientation is 1' or 'So the orientation is 2' sometimes. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method exits whenever it runs a `return` statement. So the log messages immediately after `return` statements will never get displayed.

I don't know why the actual functionality isn't working; it might be a problem somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

your issue is that you're returning an `int` (`UIInterfaceOrientation`) instead of a `BOOL`.
this method is basically the system asking your view controller if it has permission to rotate. You'll want to return `YES` for orientations you support, and `NO` for orientations you don't want to support.

something like

```
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    NSLog(@"landscape right allowed");
    return YES;
} else {
    NSLog(@"denied rotation to %i", interfaceOrientation);
    return NO;
}
```

also as others have pointed out, the return statement exits your method, passing the *return value* to the method that called it. After return is hit, no more code in your method is run.